# Cannot compile Xamarin Forms project using xamarin-fingerprint unless Linking = None

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have a Xamarin Forms project in Visual Studio 2019, for Android and iOS. I have added the smstuebe / xamarin-fingerprint plugin and added the setup code, but haven't implemented the actual fingerprint (etc) code yet.

I have to set the Android project linker properties to "Linking = None" for the project to run on a physical device. If I set it to "Sdk assemblies only", the app will crash upon start-up.

The Github page here https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint#android-code-shrinker-proguard--r8 mentions a potential problem if using Proguard or r8 but I'm not using either.

I tried adding a proguard.cfg file but it didn't have any effect.

I tried adding "com.samsung.**" to the field "Skip linking assemblies" but that didn't work either.

For now, I have set the project to "Linking = None" but that is not ideal.

How do I configure my Android project, in Visual Studio 2019, to allow linking but also allow xamarin-fingerprint to work?

Comment: report the issue on github, so that the developer of the lib can fix it

Comment: @magicandre1981 I was hoping that someone had experienced the same problem and either had a solution or a workaround. I have searched the github issues for help but found nothing related.

Comment: I have raised the issue on github, but not had any response https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint/issues/210